# Node/Mongoose returning only returning one document when using find() on production server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, mongoose

Running this locally works fine and returns every document in the collection where the query matches ... however, when I deploy this to a production machine (aws ec2 micro) all my db services which use find(), only return a single document.

I'm seeing this behavior regardless of the model I query.

```
readAll: async () => {
    const data = await App.find({ active: true }).lean();
    console.log(data); 
    // prints out [ { _id: 5c2a566608cc4062705474e6, ... } ]
    return res.new(true, text.keys[lang].app.success, data);
}
```

I feel like it's something obvious, but I just can't see it. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance for any ideas, driving me nuts.

Related dependencies are:
node 8.9.4
express 4.16.4
mongoose 5.2.6

Comment: My question may sounds silly. Are you sure that is the same database? If you use local databases on both environments, your collections may not be the same.

Comment: When you perform a 'count', is the total correct? Does removing '{ active: true }'  make a difference?

Comment: @dimitristseggenes good question, I checked and it looks to be the same database. The only other dbs are admin, config and local which I checked all to see if I had inadvertently made a apps collection someplace but I do only have one apps collection in the dbs I am using. It has a count of 2 and a find() from the mongo shell returns the correct docs.

Comment: @MoA ... hmmm, I get a count of 1 at runtime.

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. Basically the records where not in the database by the time I was attempting to read them. I assumed the earlier await would guarantee the records were written and available but maybe this is not the case. Checking the count was very helpful, thanks to both of you!

Comment: Glad you got it to work!